# How to add tags using taggit in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I am trying to add tags to my blog app using django admin but every-time I add a tag through the admin console, I get this error `Can't call similar_objects with a non-instance manager`

Is this because I am not saving the the tags in the admin or is this because I implemented taggit wrongly?

This is where I define my view and display and article, I try to grab similar articles using taggit

```
def article(request, slug):
    article = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).values()
    article_info = {
        "articles": article,
        "related_articles" : Post.tags.similar_objects()
    }

    return render(request, 'article.htm', article_info)
```

**Update**

This is how my post model looks like

```
STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author_biography = models.TextField(default="N/A")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    upload_image = models.ImageField(default="default.png", blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: What does your `Post` model look like? You need to figure out where `Post` gets a `TaggableManager` in order to call `similar_objects`

Comment: I have added my model code. I initialize it in the Posts model and I am able to add the tag through the admin, the issue comes in when I need to access related articles that's where I get this error

Comment: In your view you are using tags on a ```Model``` and not on a ```Model instance```. I guess the correct approach is ```"related_articles" = article.tags.similar_objects()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I see the problem.

You are trying to access tags on the class `Post` and not an instance of `Post`. However, you're also using `filter()` and `values()` and the variable name is singular, so I think there's perhaps a misunderstanding there as well.

I assume the kind of thing you want to do is this;

```
def article(request, slug):
    article = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    article_info = {
        "article": article,
        "related_articles" : article.tags.similar_objects()  # Instance of Post is article
    }

    return render(request, 'article.htm', article_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this type of structure is made using [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationships.

Going this way, your code should look like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

To add a tag to a post:

```
post_obj = Post.objects.get(title="le title")
tag = Tag.objects.get(name="le name")
post_obj.tag.add(tag)
```

To query:

```
post_obj = Post.objects.get(title="le title")
tags_in_post = post_obj.tag.all()
```

This should facilitate your page rendering. Assuming you want to display every post and, within it, every that, your code should be something like this:

```
// in the end of the view function:
return render(request, 'article.htm', context={'post': article_info})

// inside the template:

{% for p in post %}
<li> <span> {{p.title}} </span>

    {% for tag in post.tag %}
    <ul> {{tag.name}} </ul>
    {% endfor %}

</li>
{% endfor %}
```